# How to reset credentials of shared network in windows 11?

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, samba

I have a server with windows 11 and I have a client computer with windows 11 too.

Until now, to connect to a shared folder in the server, in the file explorer of the client I write: \x.x.x.x\MyShared folder. Then I was promted for the credentials. I use a user and password in the server and I never saved the credentials, because I want to be prompted always.

But sice few weeks ago, I am not prompted and I I get an error that says I don't have permissions. I would like to know how I could delete the credentials for that.

I check the manager credentials of the user in panel control, but I don't have any credentials related. Anyway, I delete all the windows credentials that I had. Anyway I knew that it wouldn't solve the problem because this problem happens with another users in the same client computer.

In the server, if I check the events of SMB Server, I can see that I get the error 1006. And in tihs error I can see that the a client tried to connect. The client is the IP of my client computer, but the user that is received is not correct, because the user that SMB Server receives is [NameServer][UserLoggedInClientComputer]. It is a mix of server name and user of the client computer, so how it doesn't exist in the server, it is the reason why I don't have permission.

So for some reason the client send a wrong user, but I am not prompted, so I can't send use the correct credentials. I would like to know if there is some way to reset the shared network credentials to be prmpted again.

Thanks.

EDIT: In the client I have tried to use the following command:

```
NET USE * \\server_name\share_name
```

It is said the user is not correct and prompt me for the credentials, I give the credentials of the user in the server, but I get the same error. In the server, I check the event of SMBServer and I see  that still the user that is received by the user is the user of the client computer, not the user that I used when I was prompted by the credentials.

EDIT 2:

I have tried to add a new credential in the user account of my client computer: x.x.x.x\UserInServer and it works. If I delete the credential then I am not prompted and I don't have premissions to connect.

So it seems that if I have set the credentials it uses, if not, it usea wrong credentials and it doesn't work.

Also I would like to be prompted to can decide with which user I want to connect.

Comment: Try this command: `net use \\server_name\share_name /user:USERNAME *` or perhaps `net use \\server_name\share_name *`.

Comment: if I use the first command I get tihs error: multiple connections to a server or shared resource for a user is not allowed. Disconnect all and trya gain.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in cmd or powershell:

```
NET USE * /DELETE
```

remember to input `Y` when prompt `Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N)`